# Why is my xml file reader class not working?

Tags: xml, actionscript-2

I'm trying to a make a simple class in an actionscript file that handles the reading in and parsing/managing of an xml file.  This class takes a movieclip as a parameter and has the movie clip act according to the results of the import.  I've tried this:

```
class FileReader {
    var menu:MovieClip;
    function FileReader(newMenu) {
        menu = newMenu;
    }
    //Load the specified xml file
    function loadFile(fileName) {
        menu.gotoAndStop("loading");
        var name = levelName+".xml";
        var xmlFile = new XML();
        xmlFile.ignoreWhite = true;
        xmlFile.load(name);
        xmlFile.onLoad = function() {
            //Parse Input
            menu.gotoAndStop("loaded");
        };
    }
}
```

For some reason, when the code reaches the onLoad function, the file loads properly but the application has no more knowledge of the existence of the menu movieclip.  If I try to trace any attributes of the menu, it says it is undefined.  So then I tried this:

```
class FileReader {
    var menu:MovieClip;
    var xmlFile:XML;
    function FileReader(newMenu) {
        menu = newMenu;
    }
    //Load the specified xml file
    function loadFile(fileName) {
        menu.gotoAndStop("loading");
        var name = fileName+".xml";
        xmlFile = new XML();
        xmlFile.ignoreWhite = true;
        xmlFile.load(name);
        xmlFile.onLoad = function() {
            //Parse Input
            menu.gotoAndStop("loaded");
        };
    }
}
```

In this case, the xml file won't load at all, and the xmlFile object is undefined.  What's going on here and why are neither of these approaches working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of silly, but I've finally found a way to make this work:

```
class FileReader {
    var menu:MovieClip;
    function FileReader(newMenu) {
        menu = newMenu;
    }
    //Load the specified xml file
    function loadFile(fileName) {
        menu.gotoAndStop("loading");
        var newMenu:MovieClip = menu;   //Make a refernce to menu here
        var name = levelName+".xml";
        var xmlFile = new XML();
        xmlFile.ignoreWhite = true;
        xmlFile.load(name);
        xmlFile.onLoad = function() {
                //Parse Input
                newMenu.gotoAndStop("loaded"); //Call the refence rather than the actual object
        };
    }
}
```

By making a new reference to the menu, the onLoad function can use this reference to talk to the actual menu movie clip.  I guess that works.

Answer (score 0):

By using the first approach, I found that I could simply pass the movie clip as a parameter.  The function would then recognize the movie clip and act properly as expected.  Still confused as to why it won't work without the parameter passing though.

**EDIT:**
I guess that actually didn't work as I had thought.  I'm still trying though!  Anyone with other thoughts?